# Can't get google maps to load within a bootstrap modal until the window is resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

It shows as grayed out until the page is resized, usually when I open the console window, and close it the map suddenly loads, ether than that it stays as still color, there are multiple maps on a single page aswell,

Google maps

[image]

I tried multiple methods like adding a google maps trigger,

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map{{ $article->id }}, 'load');
```

And initializing the function on the anchor to open the modal windows

```
$('a[href="#view-article-modal{{ $article->id }}"]').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
    initAutocomplete();
});
```

It runs in a foreach loop to load all the article maps,

Any help would be much appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `resize()` function when the modal opens using [Bootstrap's Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', (e) => {
    this.resizeMap();
})

resizeMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.options);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for replying so quickly, tried it out now, though still the same error, and adding an id to the anchor and using an onclick event, still wouldn't fix it

Comment: @JavonLegend Updated the answer, please have a look & let me know if this works?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out, still wouldn't work, though if a open one of the modal windows while the page is still loading that specific map in the modal works, and the others don't. I also tried changing resize to load, that didn't fix it either

Comment: Your method worked now, I was initializing the function after it had loaded, but this works perfectly, Thanks:)

Comment: Its my pleasure @JavonLegend